# Does NetSuite allow the usage of dynamic groups when selecting a group for a script deployments audience?

Tags: netsuite

I have created a custom dynamic group that uses a search to find all employees that have access to a certain record. I wish to make it so the script only runs for people in the group without creating a new role however I want the group to be dynamic as when new users get access to the record it will update the group.

the issue I'm having is my dynamic group isn't showing up under 'groups' in audience for the script deployment and I was wondering if dynamic group cant be used in this way or this is something that I might have done wrong. the group and the searched used are not private.

Answer (score 0):

Only static groups.

What I have done in cases like this is to use script to add the new user to the static group. This may result in a cascade of userevent and workflow scripts to manage group membership but adding a user to a group is pretty simple. e.g.,

```js
record.attach({
    record:{
        type:'employee',
        id:empId
    },
    to:{
        type: 'entitygroup', 
        id:groupId
    }
});
```